# WooCommerce Empty cart after payment with custom gateway API

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I'm working on custom API for Merchant Safe Unipay (MSU) for woocommerce and need to change quantity after successful payment.

Here is process:

1. Customer collect articles in shopping bag
2. When click on "Pay All" it is redirected to MSU where need to fill Credit Card info
3. After payment, MSU return him back to website where PHP send emails and print message about payment.

All works well but can't find hook where and how to mark all products from shopping card payed and change quantity.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Yes! Thanks. I need empty cart after payment inside my plugin.

Answer (score 6):

Normally after payment process, the customer is redirected to "Thank you" page (or "Order received" where customer can review his payed order)… Normally the cart is emptied somewhere (I don't remember where exactly).

So if not emptied, you need to do it for example with *(2 different hooks options)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'order_received_empty_cart_action', 10, 1 );
// or 
// add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'order_received_empty_cart_action', 10, 1 );
function order_received_empty_cart_action( $order_id ){
    WC()->cart->empty_cart();
}
```

The Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

You will have to test that, to see if it's convenient…

Comment: Thank you for this, I will test and answer you shortly.

Comment: I test this and realy clean cart but not change quantity after payment. This work fine but missing quantity part. Thanks!

Comment: @IvijanStefanStipić You never test this code or you never give me any feed back on it.

Comment: I test, this made empty cart but quantity is not updated on the purchase. I find somwhere some solution but must find it. Is long time ago. If you know solution you can update answer and I can mark solved.

Answer (score 1):

With this code the payment is skipped. (**Versión WC 3.5.7**).

I include the code of `class-wc-checkout.php` lines 983 - 989:

```
   do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', $order_id, $posted_data, $order );

   if ( WC()->cart->needs_payment() ) {
       $this->process_order_payment( $order_id, $posted_data['payment_method'] );
   } else {
       $this->process_order_without_payment( $order_id );
   }
```

If we clean the cart, it takes the else route:

```
 $this->process_order_without_payment( $order_id );
```