# Get the order ID in checkout page before payment process

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

In WooCommerce, I need to get **`order ID`** right in checkout page of WooCoommerce, **before payment, when the order is created.**

I look at all sessions and tried to find out when order goes for payment in **`order_awaiting_payment`** session, but I need it before going for payment. 
So I think about a solution that is make order when checkout page loaded (In fact make it ready for payment) and when checkout real complete update it.

How to get order ID in checkout page before order go for payment in WooCommerce?

I think there is some hook for this but I can't find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a custom function hooked in  [**`woocommerce_checkout_order_processed`**](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-checkout.php#L935) action hook. 
Since woocommerce 3.0+ version, here Is the corresponding core code located in [**`process_checkout()`**](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-checkout.php#L935) function.

```
// Since WooCommerce version 3.0+
do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', $order_id, $posted_data, $order );
```

and below WooCommerce 3.0 version:

```
// Since WooCommerce version 2.1+ (before version 3.0+)
do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', $order_id, $this->posted );
```

So there is 2 cases depending which version of woocommerce you are using:

> **Since WooCommerce 3.0+** you can use 2 additional arguments in your hooked function **and you will not need to create an instance of the order object** as you get **`$order`** already as an argument.
>   You will be able also to access the posted data directly through **`$posted_data`** argument.

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'action_checkout_order_processed', 10, 3);
function action_checkout_order_processed( $order_id, $posted_data, $order ) {
   // Do something
}
```

> **Since WooCommerce 2.1+** *(Before WooCommerce 3.0)*, you have only the **`$order_id`** as argument, so you might be need to get an instance of **`$order`** object with [**`wc_get_order()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_order.html) function:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'action_checkout_order_processed', 10, 1);
function action_checkout_order_processed( $order_id ) {
   // get an instance of the order object
   $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

   // Do something
}
```

*The Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Answer (score 4):

so unfortunately you cannot access the order_id on the checkout page itself because the order has not been created yet. Though this is true, the cart data is temporarily saved as a 'session' as WooCommerce calls it. this may help you a bit with your issue with passing information to an iFrame if you can tweak it a bit.

The way you can do this is by getting the information from the WC_session:

```
$cart_data = WC()->session->get('cart');
```

Once you do that, you will be able to access the cart data hierarchy as stored by WooCommerce by using a key index such as 'product_id' :

```
$cart_data[array_keys($cart_data)[0]]['product_id'];
```

Here is the list of valid cart data keys:

key
product_id
variation_id
variation (Array)
quantity
data_hash
line_tax_data (Array)
line_subtotal
line_subtotal_tax
line_total
line_tax

Answer (score 0):

If you just look into [`class-wc-checkout.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-checkout.php#L935) file at line number 935 you will see that there is an action `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` which pass `$order_id` as an argument.

So this should work for you:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'wh_pre_paymentcall');

function wh_pre_paymentcall($order_id) {

    //create an order instance
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    //$payment_method = $order->payment_method_title;
    //$status = $order->get_status();

    // write your custom logic over here.
}
```

*Code goes in `functions.php` file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*

Related Question: [WooCommerce Get Order Product Details Before Payment in Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42784865/5019802) *(also read the comments)*

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for your great response but actually i need to pass order_id to an iframe that is in checkout page, so i need to access to it when checkout page loaded. i think this hook do action just before going to payment and can't access to order_id when i want whit this hook